# Arch Linux: Strange version mismatch when trying to install UWSGI with pacman. Is this common / trivial?

Tags: pacman

When I run `pacman -S uwsgi` or `pacman -S community/uwsgi` I get the following error:

```
resolving dependencies...
looking for inter-conflicts...

Packages (6): jansson-2.5-2  libxml2-2.9.1-5  libyaml-0.1.4-3
              python2-2.7.6-1  sqlite-3.8.2-1  uwsgi-1.9.20-1

Total Download Size:    0.27 MiB
Total Installed Size:   69.85 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] Y
:: Retrieving packages ...

error: failed retrieving file 'uwsgi-1.9.20-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from
    archlinux.mirrors.uk2.net : The requested URL returned
    error: 404 Not Found
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed to commit transaction (download library error)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

This would indicate to me that the package is not on the server.   However I tried a number of mirrors and got the same result.

I then investigated further, by directing my web browser to the [mirror directory](http://archlinux.mirrors.uk2.net/community/os/x86_64/) and confirmed that there is a `uwsgi` package there, but the version is later:

```
uwsgi-1.9.21.1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

I am fairly new to Arch so don't know if I'm missing something obvious here.  On Debian my response would be to run `apt-get update`, but can't find a similar facility in `pacman`:  My understanding is that the `-S` option will take care of that as well as installing the package.

Could this be a case of mirrors not being synced properly, or am I missing something simple at the client end?

If the mirror contains a later version, why isn't my `pacman` command picking that up?

Answer (score 1):

Synching my local mirror database *and* doing a system upgrade with `pacman -Syu` solved it.

Comment: Pretty new to Arch myself. I read [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Installing_package_groups) in their wiki in particular a warning about partial upgrades and to never refresh the package list before installing an app. Indeed, if there was a new sync, one should do `pacman -Syu` before installing a package.